# Google API CPP Client - Using Service Account

Tags: c++, gmail-api, google-api-cpp-client

Does the Google API CPP Client Library support Authorization using Service Account?

I could not find an example of how to use the Service Account when using the CPP Client library from https://github.com/google/google-api-cpp-client/

The sample available only demonstrate using Client Secret for installed application

```
flow_.reset(OAuth2AuthorizationFlow::MakeFlowFromClientSecretsPath( client_secrets_file, config_->NewDefaultTransportOrDie(), &status));
```

Comment: I found this link http://www.example-code.com/unicodeCpp/http_xoauth2_access_token.asp for c++ service account. But I am not sure whether this is the one you are looking for. It should be almost similar to http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-api-with-a-service-account/

Answer (score 0):

I've spend quite some time figuring this out. The harsh answer is no.
Compared to the Python or PHP version of this library, the CPP version is pretty much [outdated](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/cpp/).

A quick solution might be to fetch the required data from Google and write the result to a file using the Python client libraries. I.e. with `std::system()`. Then parse the file from your C++ application.

Comment: There are new updates to the library and the new one does support Service Account.